# How to install Ganglia 3.4.0 in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, server

I am new to this environment. I am trying to install **ganglia-monitor-core3.4.0** in Ubuntu 11.10.

But I am getting a `error code 1` while executing the configure commands.

Can I do the installation from the root user? Because in an installation guide that I've found, the prompt of terminal started with `%`, where as for root user it displays `#` in the terminal. If you come across any installation materials or tutorials please let me know ASAP.

Comment: New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the FAQ. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to a [supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable)

Comment: @saji89 it's a year old if you forgot to read the question... But since its abandoned we can close it as too localized.

Comment: @Alvar, Sorry. My bad. I had read the question, but I didn't notice the date. :)

Answer (score 1):

To install Ganglia just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on
your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

> > On Ubuntu nodes:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo apt-get install ganglia-monitor
> > ```
> >
> > (this installs the service ganglia-monitor, which is gmond)
> >
> > On Ubuntu web interface machine:
> >
> > ```
> > sudo apt-get install ganglia-webfrontend
> > ```
> >
> > (this installs gmetad and the web frontend)
>
> Configuration:
>
> - Stats Generation Boxes
> - Stats Collection Box(es)
> - Ganglia-webfrontend (gmetad)
> - Hadoop Statics in Ganglia <sup>1</sup>

[Read more](http://www.supertom.com/code/ganglia_notes.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ganglia](http://www.supertom.com/code/ganglia_notes.html)</sup>

Comment: Does 11.10 have ganglia 3.4.0 then?